# Same table relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to have an association mapping a table to itself?

e.g.

```
Table:  
ConditionId  
ConditionName 
... 
...  
ParentConditionId
```

where we can have many ParentConditionIds each mapping to the same ConditionId.

I've tried a one to many mapping but I'm getting an error when there is no children.

Comment: what kind of error do you get? When there is no children, it means it's a special situation that you should check for null.

Comment: Note - I got this error due to a different case: the mapping on a stored proc was incorrect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Put the FK in your database and the wizard will map it correctly. Make sure ParentConditionId is nullable.

Comment: Thanks. My ParentconditionId wasn't nullable.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look tutorial which can be download [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/12/18/my-christmas-present-to-the-entity-framework-community.aspx) . It explains in detail how to model self-reference table.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been on this guy's blog before but have never seen the project download.