# EF4 - Force order of execution

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship

I have three tables - Context, Session and User. And below are their simplified structure.

**User:**
UserId (Int, PK)
Email (Varchar(100))

**Context:**
ContextId (Int, PK)
UserId (Int, FK from User table)
CurrentSessionId (Int, Nullable, FK from Session table)

**Session:**
SessionId (Int, PK)
UserId (Int, FK from User table)
ContextId (Int, FK from Context table)

Below is the sequence in my code to delete a user entity.

1) Update CurrentSessionId of Context table to null where UserId = UserId to be deleted.
2) Delete all Sessions corresponding to the User
3) Delete all Contexts corresponding to the User
4) Finally Delete User.
5) Call ObjectContext.SaveChanges()

Upon calling ObjectContext.SaveChanges() I get the following exception -

*Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.*

I guess EF4 gets confused determining the execution order of first 3 statements. **Is it possible to tell EF4 what statements to execute first and what to execute next?**

One way I can work around is to call SaveChanges() after step one and then call it again after step four. But I would love to know if there are any other elegant solution than that.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517566/does-entity-framework-support-circular-references/11812560#11812560

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/d8a01422-dbcb-49df-a42d-02484e2c9aab) the order of execution cannot be forced in EF4. I had to call SaveChanges() twice once after step one and then again after step four.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with the circular reference between `Session` and `Context`; if you get rid of `Context.CurrentSessionId` then your generated `Context` object will still have a `Sessions` property you can use, but EF shouldn't get upset trying to negotiate the dependencies. You could manually add a `CurrentSession` property to `Context` like this:

```
public Session CurrentSession
{
    get { return this.Sessions.FirstOrDefault(); }
}
```

Also, if you set the `User -> Context` and `User -> Session` relationships in your EF model to cascade delete (or even better [in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937140/delete-an-object-and-all-of-its-related-entities-in-entity-framework)), then deleting a `User` becomes just two lines:

```
objectContext.Users.DeleteObject(user);
objectContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The circular reference is designed for a purpose and I have less control in the database to have it changed. Also I do not want to set cascade delete in EF4 as I have read that it will only delete the entities that are in ObjectContext's memory. And for the database cascade - I cannot get it turned on as our DBA hates it.

Comment: A DBA who just unswervingly hates cascading deletes? Even though `Context` and `Session` are meaningless without their `User`? Oh dear :( You may well be stuck with multiple calls to `SaveChanges()`.