# Unable to determine a valid ordering error when using self referencing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this schema :

[image]

`Category` entity have a reference to itself via `ParentCategoryId` field.`ParentCategoryId` field is nullable.I use Database first way.this is generated code for this `entity` :

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Category1 = new HashSet<Category>();
        this.News = new HashSet<News>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<News> News { get; set; }
}
```

when I insert a category that its `ParentCategoryId` field is nullable,every thing is ok,but when I select a value for `ParentCategoryId`I get this exception:

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values
```

Comment: [Circular dependecies in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304298/circular-dependency-in-entity-framework)

Comment: make FK nullable and you are good to go

Comment: ParentCategoryId is nullable!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a category with pk=0 and when I selected It as a parent I got mentioned error.after removing this category the problem was resolved.