# EF 5 Code-First Seeding self referencing table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Here's my code:

base class:

```
public class BaseEnt
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get;set; }
    public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

    public int InsertUserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
    public int UpdateUserID { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual User InsertUser { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdateUser { get; set; }
}
```

user entity:

```
public class User:BaseEnt
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> InsertedUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> UpdatedUsers { get; set; }

}
```

model creating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                     .HasRequired(t => t.InsertUser)
                     .WithMany(t=>t.InsertedUsers)
                     .HasForeignKey(t => t.InsertUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                     .HasRequired(t => t.UpdateUser)
                     .WithMany(t=>t.UpdatedUsers)
                     .HasForeignKey(t => t.UpdateUserID).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
```

Seed:

```
    protected override void Seed(MCFDataContext context)
    {
        context.Users.Add(new Entities.User {ID=1,Fullname="Rusty Boi ",Username="jhaskdhaksdhk",InsertUserID=1,UpdateUserID=1,UpdateDate=DateTime.Now,InsertDate=DateTime.Now });

    }
```

and here's the error i encountered in the seed part:

{"Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values."}

Comment: You are having a circular dependency.
refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/4446279/1305119

Comment: The issue you are facing is a circular reference, because the user you are trying to add, already references itself.

Answer (score 0):

what you have here is some sort of "chicken and egg" problem. Possible solutions:

- Make the foreign keys `InsertUserID` and `UpdateUserID` nullable
- Do a design change: Maybe the user table shouldn't have InsertUserID, UpdateUserID. this could be solved by introducing another base class which doesn't have the `InsertUserID` and `UpdateUserID` properties or something similar

Comment: But this design is doing fine in Database-First.Is it really not doable in Code-First?

Comment: how is that possible? you have a table with an ID and a self-referencing column called InsertUserID and UpdateUserID. How can you insert a new record when the table is empty?

Comment: I know now, maybe I inserted the first row before creating the relationship.